# How can I get rid of the return there?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, positioning

I try to get rid of the following return in my wordpress loop. I want to display a thumbnail next to the entry and it looks terrible:

[image: the situation]

I tried to use padding for the entry but it's worse!!

Here's my code:

```css
#thumbnail_single {
  float: left;
}
.entry_single {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="single">

  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <h2 class="title_single"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

  <div id="thumbnail_single">

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
  <div class="entry_single">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</div>
<!-- single -->
```

Thank you for your help with that!

Comment: you should set a margin-right to image, if you want .entry_single to fall straight aside and not wrap, add overflow:hidden to .entry_single , padding will be applied also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding 20px padding to your #thumbnail_single as well

Answer (score 2):

not entirely clear to me, but 2 options depending on final result :

wraping text :

```
#thumbnail_single {
  float: left;
  margin-right:20px;
}
.entry_single {

}
```

text not wrapping under:

It involves BFC : http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/

```
#thumbnail_single {
  float: left;
}
.entry_single {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```